# Copying numeric text with leading zeroes in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro to take the contents of an Excel worksheet and export them to a CSV file (for import by another application).

My problem is that on export, any cell containing text which could be interpreted as a number is converted to a number.  This means that if the text contained leading zeroes, these are lost.

So, data like this:

> ASSETS    0100738 1/05/2003       612

would be exported as

> ASSETS,100738,1/05/2003,612

My code is:

```
Public Sub ExportSheetAsCSV(ByRef sh As Worksheet)
    Dim dataToExport As Excel.Range
    Dim newWrkbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim dstdir As String
    Dim dstpath As String

    Set dataToExport = sh.UsedRange
    Set newWrkbk = newWorkbook(1, ActiveWorkbook)
    '' Copy Step:
    newWrkbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(dataToExport.Rows.Count, dataToExport.Columns.Count).Value = dataToExport.Value

    dstdir = FSO.BuildPath(FSO.BuildPath(ActiveWorkbook.path, "CSVs"), FSO.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name))
    dstpath = FSO.BuildPath(dstdir, sh.Name & ".csv")

    MkDirStructure dstdir

    newWrkbk.SaveAs Filename:=dstpath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    newWrkbk.Close False
End Sub
```

By going through this step by step, I can see that the leading zeroes disappear at the copy step (as opposed to the save step).

This question, [VBA: preceding zeros dropped when copied over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493780/vba-preceding-zeros-dropped-when-copied-over), covers a similar issue, but none of the given answers work for me.  The accepted answer is to convert the offending cells to text (and the other top answer is to do the same using VBA's numberFormat), but

1. I don't know in advance which cells will need to be converted so this is inconvenient
2. the value of the cells is updated by a formula so if I convert to text, then the text of the formula becomes the value of the cell
3. Date values will be converted to their integer representation
4. This doesn't even work.  Having converted cells to text, the leading zeroes are still stripped.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a little bit more work, the workaround I found is to do a copy/paste-special rather than to assign the value of target range to the value of the source.

So, this line:

```
newWrkbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(dataToExport.Rows.Count, dataToExport.Columns.Count).Value = dataToExport.Value
```

is replaced by

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set oldWrkbk = ActiveWorkbook

dataToExport.Copy
newWrkbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
oldWrkbk.Activate
```

Where a reference to the source workbook is cached so that we can return to where we started before closing the new file.

Answer (score 2):

' convert the format of all cells to text and add the below line for the required range of cells...before copying the data..

Range("B1:X100000").NumberFormat = "@"

Comment: Hi bp696, thanks for the response. This is the same as the second answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493780/vba-preceding-zeros-dropped-when-copied-over which didn't work for me. Looking at this again, I think that I misunderstood that answer, and yours. I had tried using .NumberFormat = "@" on the range from which I was copying, which did not solve the problem. If I reformat the range to which I'm copying, that solves the leading zeroes issue. Can you confirm that you mean to reformat the target range, rather than the source range, as text?

Comment: However, using this solution introduces a problem wherein dates are reformatted from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy which would cause other problems.

Comment: @tensorproduct i meant the target range....you can select the range apart from the date column and convert them to text....

Comment: I'm afraid that I plan to use this macro on all manner of spreadsheets without knowing where date columns might be in advance (and in many cases, dates won't be neatly confined to a single column).